# how to get contact after google login

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

I am using google login and use this  code for auth

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google OAuth Login Example");
$client->setClientId($client_id);
$client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->setDeveloperKey($simple_api_key);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"));
$objOAuthService = new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
```

Now here get access token from client and use this access token from   fetching user contacts

```
$accessToken = client->getAccessToken();
  if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $userData = $objOAuthService->userinfo->get();
    $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();

 }
```

Now i want to login user contact user this api and access token which i have got from during auth of google users

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=' . $max_results . '&oauth_token=' . $accessToken;
$xmlresponse = curl_file_get_contents($url);
echo 'contact result='.$xmlresponse;
```

But i got 401 http status and not able to fetch user contact. Please help me how i got login user contact emails using access token which i got during auth .

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter name is access_token not oauth_token.

try this:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=' . $max_results . '&access_token=' . $accessToken;
$xmlresponse = curl_file_get_contents($url);
echo 'contact result='.$xmlresponse;
```

Note: the google contacts API is an old GData API you wont be able to use the Google php client library to access it.   You should look into the Google People API I have found that the data returned is similar to that which is in Google contacts.